# PagSeguro e PagSeguroConfigWrapper

Tags: php, laravel

Estou trabalhando com PagSeguro no Laravel 5.3, o problema é a Class PagSeguroConfigWrapper que eu preciso gerar para fazer a autenticação, eu faço todos os passos descrito na documentação e funciona somente se eu utilizar a autenticação após a instancia da class PagSeguroPaymentRequest. 
Veja o exemplo:

**Funciona**

```
    new PagSeguroPaymentRequest();
    $credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();

    $transaction = PagSeguroTransactionSearchService::searchByCode($credentials, $transaction_code);
```

**Não Funciona, erro: `Credentials not set`**

```
    $credentials = PagSeguroConfig::getAccountCredentials();

    $transaction = PagSeguroTransactionSearchService::searchByCode($credentials, $transaction_code);
```

Comment: Aparentemente você está usando o https://github.com/pagseguro/php3. Eu também tive o mesmo problema com a configuração, a solução por mais feio que isso seja é criar a classe Wrapper lá no [vendor/pagseguro/php3/source/Configuration](https://github.com/pagseguro/php3/tree/master/source/Configuration). Inclusive tem um arquivo de exemplo nesse diretório. Edit: Eu também tive que chamar o `PagSeguro\Library::initialize();` antes de utilizar a qualquer outro método da lib.